# Show SQL error in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, exception, error-handling

I have the following stored procedure. But I don't know how to throw an error from SQL Server and show it on JavaScript Alert.

Here is the stored procedure

```
Begin
    if EXISTS(select * from POS_Transactions where ID = @transId) 
    Begin
        declare @totalAmount money

        select @totalAmount = TotalAmount 
        from POS_Transactions 
        where ID = @transId and PAN = @pan

        update pos_transactions 
        set transactiontypeid = 3 
        where id = @transId

        update cardbalance 
        set cardbalance = (cardbalance + @totalAmount),
            totalredemption = (totalredemption - @totalAmount) 
        where pan = @pan
    END
    Else
        --Show Error Here
    BEGIN
END
```

And here is the VB code:

```
Try
  If txtEmbossLine.Text <> "" And txtTransactionId.Text <> "" Then
  Utilities.VoidRedemption(txtEmbossLine.Text, txtTransactionId.Text)
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Redemption Voided successfully')</script>")
  Else
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter both fields')</script>")
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  Response.Write(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38650/Overview-of-Error-Handling-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to [`throw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) an exception from SQL Server:

```
throw 50001, 'Some error', 1
```

Your `try ... catch` in your C# code will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Catch SQL exception in vb.net.

```
Try
     //Do your stuff
Catch ex as SqlException
  Dim errors = ex.Errors
  // inspect errors to decide if this is the condition you want to catch
  Dim shouldCatch As Boolean = ... 
     // Code that acts on the specific error condition
  If shouldCatch Then
  Else
     Throw // rethrow error
  End If
 End Try
```